# What mean "precise" in apt sources.list entry

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I tried to find an answer on the Internet but only thing that I found is that it determines architecture but it not seems logical.

So what dose “precise” mean in follow line?

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe restricted multiverse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`precise` is the release name of 12.04.

Explanation of the Repository format from [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine#Explanation_of_the_Repository_Format):

> **deb**: These repositories contain binaries or precompiled packages. These repositories are required for most users.
>
> **deb-src**: These repositories contain the source code of the packages. Useful for developers.
>
> `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`: The URI (Uniform Resource Identifier), in this case a location on the internet. See the official
>   mirror list or the self-maintained mirror list to find other mirrors.
>
> **precise** is the release name or version of your distribution.
>
> **main**, **restricted**, **universe** and **multiverse** are the section names or components. There can be several section names, separated by spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much, maybe it cause this problem? http://superuser.com/questions/478260/apt-unable-to-locate-sun-java5-jdk Thank you very much if you will put attention to the problem.

Comment: It existing something for all releases?

Comment: Each release has its own release name. I'll look into the other question now.