# APT unable to locate sun-java5-jdk

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have following Ubuntu:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
```

With following apt installed:

```
apt 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.2 for i386 compiled on Jun 15 2012 14:41:15
```

This is content of sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe main multiverse restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports universe main multiverse restricted

# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

I made:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

I didn't had errors.
When I do:

```
sudo apt-cache search ^sun-java
```

I have only:

```
sun-javadb-client - Java DB client
sun-javadb-common - Java DB common files
sun-javadb-core - Java DB core
sun-javadb-demo - Java DB demo
sun-javadb-doc - Java DB documentation
sun-javadb-javadoc - Java DB javadoc
```

And finally when I do:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java5-jdk
```

I have:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sun-java5-jdk
```

But!!! The package is existing in the repository (!!!):

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/s/sun-java5/
```

Any ideas?
Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't install `sun-java5-jdk` is because it doesn't exist in the repository anymore. It was [removed because of a security risk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/java-to-be-removed-from-ubuntu-uninstalled-from-user-machines/).

If you need to use Java, you could install OpenJDK.